# How to use particle editor for libgdx?

Tags: tools, assets, particles, libgdx

In the libgdx wiki, [this particle editor](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ParticleEditor) is recommended. And [this blog was helpful](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1255). But the problem is that I am not sure yet how to use it for my game. Let's say I want to have a fire-effect in my game. How can I get help for this particle editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found [the answer in here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ParticleEmitterTest.java). You can directly use the output of the editor in the API. It's really cool.

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: This answer would be better if it included a summary of the steps at this external link, so the information remains accessible even if the link rots in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 3D particle effects, there is also a "new" Wiki page for using the particles: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-Particle-Effects

Comment: This answer would be better if it summarized the main points you hope a reader will glean from this wiki, so that the information remains accessible even if the Wiki page changes its URL, goes offline, becomes unavailable from a particular region, etc.